# Oracle : Identifying duplicates in a table without index

Tags: oracle, plsql, duplicates

When I try to create a unique index on a large table, I get a unique contraint error.  The unique index in this case is a composite key of 4 columns.

Is there an efficient way to identify the duplicates other than :

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, count(*)
from Table1
group by col1, col2, col3, col4
having count(*) > 1
```

The explain plan above shows full table scan with extremely high cost, and just want to find if there is another way.

Thanks !

Comment: http://www.remote-dba.cc/oracle_tips_duplicate_rows.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try creating a non-unique index on these four columns first.  That will take O(n log n) time, but will also reduce the time needed to perform the `select` to O(n log n).

You're in a bit of a bind here -- any way you slice it, the entire table has to be read in at least once.  The naïve algorithm runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, unless the query optimizer is clever enough to build a temporary index/table.

Comment: After you have resolved your non-unique issue, you can enforce the unique constraint using the non-unique index you have created. It won't let you create a unique index while you have a non-unique index on the same columns, so if you REALLY want a unique index, create your non-unique index as create index t_ix on table1(col1,col2,col3,col4,1); With the literal at the end, it won't stop you later creating the unique index on col1,col2,col3,col4 and then dropping the non-unique index

Comment: All replies indicated that there is no easy way out of this problem.  But this answer also gave me an approach, so I picked this as the best answer to my problem. Thanks Jeff.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the EXCEPTIONS INTO clause to trap the duplicated rows.

If you don't already have an EXCEPTIONS table create one using the provided script:

```
SQL>  @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/ultexcpt.sql
```

Now you can attempt to create a unique constraint like this

```
alter table Table1
add  constraint tab1_uq UNIQUE (col1, col2, col3, col4)
exceptions into exceptions
/
```

This will fail but now your EXCEPTIONS table contains a list of all the rows whose keys contain duplicates, identified by ROWID.  That gives you a basis for deciding what to do with the duplicates (delete, renumber, whatever).

**edit**

As others have noted you have to pay the cost of scanning the table once.  This approach gives you a permanent set of the duplicated rows, and ROWID is the fastest way of accessing any given row.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no index on those columns, that query would have to do a full table scan - no other way to do it really, unless one or more of those columns is already indexed.

You could create the index as a non-unique index, then run the query to identify the duplicate rows (which should be very fast once the index is created).  But I doubt if the combined time of creating the non-unique index then running the query would be any less than just running the query without the index.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you need to look for a duplicate of every single row in a table. No way to do this effectively without an index.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a quicker way unfortunately.